# How can I remove an object in Kotlin from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I have a LoadingListView which contains this:

```
 var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>? = null
    private set
```

When I delete a item, I do this:

```
adapter?.remove(wallboardToDelete)
```

This says: `required Nothing! found MyObject`

How can I fix this?
I tried using in my ListView `ArrayAdapter<Any>?` and the removeWorks, but then my init from all my classes that extend gives me an issue saying that:
I need ArrayAdapter instead of MyArrayAdapterFromListExtendingThis.

Comment: Try `var adapter: ArrayAdapter<Any>? = null`. Btw consider using `val` over `var`!

Comment: I want just "wallboardToDelete" to delete, not the full ArrayAdapter.
That item is being selected from a "for loop" that checks what to remove

Comment: That should work with my solution as well. Don't you have a common interface or super class which all items extend from`?

Comment: From your last section I assume that you use  this code in an abstract class or so?

Comment: Yes. ArrayAdapter is from a class (LoadingListView) that is being Extended by others.
https://pastebin.com/qEAHdt15

Comment: That's not true here! Your class is neither abstract nor open so you can't extended it in Kotlin. Why don't you use a generic in your class? See my answer for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your declaration from `ArrayAdapter<*>` to `ArrayAdapter<Any>`.
<*> is used for represent a fixed type wich you don't know what is, so it can contain Int type, but only Int then

Comment: Also take a look on this link for more information: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections

Comment: Thanks. I did that and then when I init I would cast to ArrayAdapter<Any> my adapters, and it works now :D

Comment: actually very interesting, did not know that `<*>` is used just for one single type

Answer (score 0):

From the code you postes on the website in the comment why don't you use something like this?

```
class LoadingListView<T> : RelativeLayout {
    var adapter: ArrayAdapter<T>? = null
        private set

    // ...

    fun init(adapter: ArrayAdapter<T>, loadingListListener: LoadingListListener, noTextRes: Int) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```